# Handling dd/mm/yyyy format in symfon2/Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

What should happen here is this:

- Only `dd/mm/yyyy` format will be accepted for **DOB**.
- If different format given then "*The DoB field must have a valid format*." message should read on the screen **BUT** this message should be coming from the **ENTITY**, **not form TYPE** set with '*invalid_message*' attribute.

**JFYI:** I can define **$dob** as '*string*' in the `entity` and as '*text*' in the form `type` to make whole process work but it is not good practise. The reason is I don't want `varchar` field for $dob in database, I want `date` field.

**PERSON ENTITY** (*Note: This is the only place I want form validation takes place*):

```
namespace Se\HirBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Person
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $firstname
     * 
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "The Firstname field should not be blank.")
     * @Assert\Length(max = "100", maxMessage = "The Firstname field cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters length.")
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 100)
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @var date $dob
     * 
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "The DoB field should not be blank.")
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern = "/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/", message = "The DoB field must have a valid format.")
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type = "date", length = 10)
     */
    protected $dob;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updated
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable = true)
     */
    protected $updated;




    /**
     * Gets triggered only on insert
     * 
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime("now");
    }

    /**
     * Gets triggered every time on update
     * 
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function onPreUpdate()
    {
        $this->updated = new \DateTime("now");
    }




    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstname
     *
     * @param string $firstname
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set dob
     *
     * @param string $dob
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setDob($dob)
    {
        $this->dob = $dob;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dob
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDob()
    {
        return $this->dob;
    }
}
```

**Form TYPE file:**

```
namespace Se\HirBundle\Form\Type\Person;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CreateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->setAction($options['action'])
                ->setMethod('POST')

                ->add('firstname', 'text',
                        array('label' => 'Firstname', 'error_bubbling' => true))

                ->add('dob', 'date',
                        array('label' => 'DoB', 'widget' => 'single_text',
                            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'input'  => 'datetime', 'error_bubbling' => true))

                ->add('create', 'submit',
                        array('label' => 'Create Person'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'personcreate';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'Se\HirBundle\Entity\Person'));
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
namespace Se\HirBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Se\HirBundle\Entity\Person;
use Se\HirBundle\Form\Type\Person\CreateType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CrudController extends Controller
{
    public function createAction()
    {
        $person = new Person();

        $form = $this->createForm(new CreateType(), $person,
                array('action' => $this->generateUrl('create_submit')));

        return $this->render('SeHirBundle:Default:create.html.twig',
                array('page' => 'Create', 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }

    public function createPersonAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getMethod() != 'POST')
        {
            return new Response('Only POST method is accepted');
        }

        $person = new Person();

        $form = $this->createForm(new CreateType(), $person,
                array('action' => $this->generateUrl('create_submit')));

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $submission = $form->getData();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $person = new Person();
            $person->setFirstname($submission->getFirstname());
            $person->setDob($submission->getDob());

            $em->persist($person);
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'Person successfully created!');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('message'));
        }

        return $this->render('SeHirBundle:Default:create.html.twig',
                array('page' => 'Create', 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

**TWIG:**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ page }}{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    <b>{{ page|upper }}</b>
    <hr />
    {{ form_start(form, {attr: {novalidate:'novalidate'}}) }}
        {% if form_errors(form) != '' %}
            <div>{{ form_errors(form) }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.firstname) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.firstname) }}
        </div>

        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.dob) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.dob, {'type':'text'}) }}
        </div>

        <br />

        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form.create) }}
        </div>

    {{ form_end(form)}}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: try replacing 'text' with null, because in that way symfony2 will interpret the field as a string.

Comment: Getting built-in "This value is not valid." which is not what I want.

Comment: Need to add a data transform to translate the entity date object to/from a text string.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html.  However, eventually you will find that using the form date will save you headaches.  In fact, its doubtful that your entity validate will even work since you are storing a date object and not a string.  Might try test that first using the validator service directly.

Comment: What is `$submission`? This error is due to `$submission->getDob()` not being a `Datetime` object. Have you tried to use [`$form->handleRequest($request);`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions) in order to pass the form values to the `Person` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION in Controller:

```
$dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $submission->getDob())));
$person->setDob($dob);
```

Comment: this will work fine if you need to do it only one time, otherwise if you need it many times you need to implement a data transformer

Comment: @zizoujab : a data transformer is not necessary IMHO. I often used a `datetime` field with `$form->handleRequest($request);` and it was the value from the field was automatically transformer into a `Datetime` object. I'm pretty sure it's the same for a `date` field.

Comment: @A.L  - Do you mind sharing a small example please? I'm new in S2 so happy to different approaches. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on the [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions):

## Controller

### Start of the file

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

### Function in the controller

This controller will display the `dob` field, since this is a `Datetime` object it requires to use `format()` in order to display it. This is just an example to show that Symfony2 recognizes the date and transform it internally.

Uncommenting the lines starting with `//` would be sufficient to persist the `Person` entity with the `dob`.

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $person = new Person();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($person)
        ->add('dob', 'date',
            array(
                'label' => 'DoB',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                'invalid_message' => 'Validation error goes here',
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'input' => 'datetime' # return a Datetime object (*)
            )
        )
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        # perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
        //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //$em->persist($person);
        //$em->flush();

        return new Response($person->getDob()->format('d-m-Y'));
    }

    return $this->render(
        'YourBundle:Default:test.html.twig',
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        )
    );
}
```

(*): http://symfony.com/fr/doc/master/reference/forms/types/date.html#input

## Twig file

```twig
{{ form(form) }}
```

## routing.yml

```yaml
test:
    pattern:  /test/
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle:Default:test }
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the example. The problem is, I'm keep everything separately like validation takes placein `Person` entity, form building takes place in a `Type` file etc. If we're to set `invalid_message` when building the form (doesn't matter where ever we do), we're bypassing `Person` entity where all the validation takes places with `@Assert`. Even if we don't set it in form build, a generic message is returned like `This field is invalid` which is not nice when we have many field in the form.

Comment: This was just an example, you can use `'input' => 'datetime'` in your code by adding it in your `Type`. There is a `@Assert/Date()` assertion to check that the date is valid, you can customize the error message.

Comment: That's what I did but if the user enters an invalid format then there is a problem. Validation never reaches to `@Assert/Date()` in `Person` entity class because form builder runs its own validation against the date entered by the user in very first step and returns `This field is invalid` message although my `@Assert` returns a different dynamic error message. I don't want form bilder's messages.

Comment: Please update your question to show the current code so I can reproduce your problem. And please add the code of the `FormType` and the complete function of the controller.

Comment: Whole question updated. I'll check it tomorrow so no rush for now. Thank you